# How to define a tags / value query in Grafana 7.4?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I am having some trouble understanding [the concept of Value groups/tags in Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-value-tags/) 7.4.x with MySQL as a data source.

My main query gets the Countries

```
SELECT 
    NAME as __text, 
    id AS __value 
from 
    countries
```

The tags query gets the Continents

```
SELECT 
    NAME as __text, 
    id AS __value 
from 
    continents
```

That works so far, tags are shown in the list, but nothing happens once I click on them.

My tags query:

```
continents.$tag.*
```

The tags query seems to be the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

3 queries are involved:

The first one is under "Query Options" -> "Query": This one should list all the **values** (all the countries in your case).

The second query is the "Tags query" under "Value groups/tags": This query should list all the **Tags** you want (continents).

The third query is "Tag values query": This is where the magic happens, this query should return all the different values matching the selected tags, so, you must add a `WHERE` clause somewhere that Grafana will use to create a query to get the correct values,  `...WHERE continent = '$tag'`. <- $tag will automatically be replaced by a list of tags the user has chosen.

Be aware that the official documentation provides examples for InfluxDB datasource, since you are using MySQL, you must use SQL queries everywhere, so `continents.$tag.*` is invalid.

Comment: OK, I understand now that MySQL expects an additional WHERE stmt. However I could not figure out how to deal with "NAME as __text,  id AS __value". When I just use id as tag, the checkboxes next to the tags become selectable but selecting them has no effect on the country list. You have a '' around your $tag. Why? Does this not work with integers?